Seeking a solution to convert HTML code to a PDF
My tool code convert content to image
I am trying to convert HTML and CSS to a PDF file using JavaScript, but my current implementation with html2pdf converts the content to an image, which makes the PDF non-searchable and non-selectable. Can someone give me some solution to fix this?


window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", () => {
        const allvoice = document.getElementById("allvoice");

        var opt = {
            margin : [20,0],
            filename: 'myfile.pdf',
            image: { type: 'png', quality: 0.98 }, 
            html2canvas: {
                scale: 2,
                logging: true,
                dpi: 192,
                letterRendering: true
            },
            jsPDF: {
                unit: 'mm',
                format: 'a4',
                orientation: 'landscape',
            },
            pagebreak: {  mode: ['avoid-all', 'css', 'legacy'] }
        };

        html2pdf().from(allvoice).set(opt).toPdf().get('pdf').then(function(pdf) {
            var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
            for (i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
                pdf.setPage(i);
                pdf.setFontSize(10);
                pdf.setTextColor(100);
                pdf.text('Page ' + i + ' of ' + totalPages, (pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() / 2.3), (pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 0.8));
            }
        }).save();
    });
}



I am using html2pdf by EKOOPMANS

Please don't create multiple account to ask the same question. Consider actually editing the question to make it conform the requirements of StackOverflow

FWIW the original question should not have been closed, the wording implies it is off topic but it is not. An edit would have fixed that.

Can't see how. The actual question is "Can someone suggest a JavaScript library or provide a code example that can create searchable and selectable PDFs from HTML and CSS?" - Furthermore, I have addressed this in the initial comment in this question

@DarkBee you're right. My meaning was the intent of this question as written (How do I do x with this tool?) which I thought was also how the original question was written, was not off topic.

Nguyễn is Lý Công Thành a different user, or is that also you? There is a pending edit to this question that rewrites it.

No.
If you look this up in the documentation there is a line under known issues:

Rendered as image: html2pdf.js renders all content into an image, then
places that image into a PDF. This means text is not selectable or
searchable, and causes large file sizes. This is currently
unavoidable, however recent improvements in jsPDF mean that it may
soon be possible to render straight into vector graphics.

Source
